# React Native - Undefined is not an object when evaluating promise

Tags: reactjs, react-native

i am beginner react-native programmer . I am trying to return the responseJSON in a fetch function . I know it is asynchronous and will return promise, thus I need to use .then() , but when it says undefined is not an object.

here is the code

auth.js

```
export const onVerify = (email,password,navigation) => {
          console.log('Verifying');
          fetch('xxx',
            {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                },
                body: 'email=' + email + '&password=' + password
            })

            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                if(responseJson.status == '200') {
                  Alert.alert(
                    'Login Successful',
                    'Welcome Home'
                  );

                  let data = {
                      name: responseJson.name,
                      id : responseJson.id
                  };


                  onSignIn();
                  return responseJson

                }
```

in my signin.js

```
export default class SignIn extends React.Component{

  step(){
 onVerify(this.state.email,this.state.password,this.props.navigation).then(
      function(data) {
        console.log(data);
      }
    );
  }
```

Comment: The function ‘onVerify’ doesn’t seem to return anything.

Comment: it should return responseJson right ? @teivaz

Answer (score 0):

As said by @teivaz on the comment, your `onVerify` function returns nothing. Because the `fetch` call is asynchronous. So what you can do is return a `Promise` from `onVerify` then you'll be able to resolve it from `step` function.

This is how you can implement this,

```
export const onVerify = (email,password,navigation) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fetch('endpoint',
            {
                method,
                headers,
                body,
            })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                if(responseJson.status == '200') {
                    Alert.alert(
                        'Login Successful',
                        'Welcome Home'
                    );

                    let data = {
                        name: responseJson.name,
                        id : responseJson.id
                    };


                    onSignIn();
                    resolve(responseJson)
                }
            })
            .catch(err => reject(err));
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to catch the errors if any in `step` function.

```
export default class SignIn extends React.Component{
    step(){
        onVerify(this.state.email,this.state.password,this.props.navigation).then(
            function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        )
        .catch(err => console.log('Error occured', err));
    }
}
```